# Not able save anything from admin redirecting to 404 page

Tags: magento2, admin, 404-page

Not able save anything from admin redirecting to 404 page.
If I save any blocks or cms pages it is redirecting 404 page.How to fix this issue.

Comment: Please give detailed information about your issue like screenshot.

Comment: what is the route of the 404 page?